# Access a database without a password?

Tags: php, sql

I am new to SQL database and was wondering If a user can have access to a database without providing a password. Or do I have to pass in an empty password field `'PWD' => ''`

Sample code with password filed removed:

```
    $connInfo = array(
            'Database' => 'mystore',
            'UID' => 'admin_user',
            /*password field removed*/
            'ReturnDatesAsStrings' => true 
             );
    $connectString = sqlsrv_connect('some.sever.name', $connInfo) or die("Can't connect to the database");


    $query = 'SELECT * FROM products';
        $data = sqlsrv_query($connectString, $query) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ALL), true));

        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($data))
        {
        //Graduate
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "  " .$row['NAME'] ."  -  " .$row['EMAIL'] ." ";
        echo "</tr><br>";   
        }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($data);
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($query);
    ?>
```

I am doing this for a testing purposes and not going to upload this in to a website without a password. Can you please tell me if the syntax of the above code is valid?

Comment: *"Can you please tell me if the syntax of the above code is valid?"* - Have you tried it? Got any errors? Oh, and I remember this very same question being asked a day or so ago ;-) Yeah, code's like a fingerprint to me.

Comment: You have this tagged as `mysql`, but you're using the Microsoft driver. Did you mean `mssql`?

Comment: `I am doing this for a testing purposes` and why didn't you test it then?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes I remember this question too, the same `/*password filed removed*/` comment and sqlsrv_* functions.

Comment: A password of "" is a password, not much one admittedly. But the answer to your question, is it's not worth the effort of configuring your dbms badly in order to have a database that does not reflect a real world scenario in any sane way.

Comment: @VMai Either someone else asked it, or the OP deleted the original question. I remember some of the comments left, one being something like "doing so, would let anyone access it". I've my money on the latter ;-) Might even be a dupe account; who knows. (As per `Prix's` comment below).

Comment: [Deleted 9 minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435911/sql-database-with-empty-password-filed) created by http://stackoverflow.com/users/1255576/d-p even the text is the same

Comment: Why, oh why, can't I vote this down more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only two ways to connect to SQL Database:

1) Using SQL Password where you need to specified the credentials

2) or using domain authentication, where the credentials are same as you logged in your pc:
     Option 1: Data source=localhost; initial catalog=master;trusted connection = true
     Option 2: Data source=localhost; initial catalog=master;Integrated security=SSPI

But you can check the following link where you will find any connection string to most databases and all variants of connection:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Regards.
Majahide

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think that you can do what you say is by creating a user with an empty string as a password. You can do that directly in your RDMBS administrator.

However, from my personal point of view, that is a really dumb thing to do:

- Anyone who has that username can access your data. Even if you provide read-only permissions to such username, that would be undesirable.
- Your attempt to do such thing only denotes that you are lazy and that you are trying to take shortcuts, instead of following the (elementary) rules.

Besides that, instead of asking others to test your code, do it yourself. If you have any specific questions regarding specific problems, then feel free to ask.

**Final note:** Your question shows that you are using SQL server... but you are tagging as MySQL... was that accidental, or deliberate?

Comment: The same question about the mysql tag as yesterday :-)